# How can I call a graphql lambda from another lambda in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql

I created graphql lambda by following this instruction: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/deployment/lambda/
It works fine with API gateway. However, I need to call this lambda function from another lambda. I think I need to put `ApolloClient` in the other lambda function in order to send a graphql request. However, it doesn't work because I can't choose a right link for calling lambda. 
So I am looking for how to build the graphql request programatically. I can send the request as an event to trigger the graphql lambda.

Is there a way to do that?

For example, if I have a mutation request like:

```
 mutation sendMessage {
      sendMessage(text: "hello"){
      text
    }
```

I need to find a way to convert the request to below payload:

```
{"id":"1","type":"start","payload":{"variables":{},"extensions":{},"operationName":"sendMessage","query":"mutation sendMessage {\\n  sendMessage(text: \\"hello\\") {\\n    text\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n}\\n"}}
```

then I send this payload to the graphql lambda function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use graphQL client to perform graphQL request via API Gateway endpoint using HTTP.

Given that you have an API Gateway endpoint pointing to the graphQL server, you can perform a graphQL request to that endpoint from another lambda.

GraphQL queries to the server is simply a regular `POST` request formatted in a certain way. So if you wanted, you could use any server-side HTTP client to perform that request. However, using a library like [graphql-request](https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-request) makes it much simpler.

You can use [graphql-request](https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-request) package to perform server-side graphQL requests.

```
import { request } from 'graphql-request'

const endpoint="https://your-api-gateway-endpoint";

const headers = {
  "x-api-key": 'api-gateway-key' // if your endpoint requires API key
};

const client = new GraphQLClient(endpoint, { headers });

const query = `{
  mutation sendMessage {
      sendMessage(text: "hello"){
      text
  }
}`;

const data = await client.request(query);
console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));
```

Comment: I thought about this solution but it will give more latency for the request. It sends request to API gateway and the gateway forwards it to the lambda which is not great. Is there a way to generate the graphql request payload in the lambda and send it to the graphql lambda directly?

Comment: I do not think using lambda invoke is a good idea even if it was possible. As your client lambda will be running until your server lambda, you will pay for much higher lambda usage. Latency would be in milliseconds so I would not be concerned.